# Como incluir cor de fundo no evento do FULLCALENDAR?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Estou usando o `fullcalendar` na versao 5.5.1, e na visão de mês os eventos são exibidos apenas com uma bolinha do lado e sem cor de fundo, a não ser que que o evento contenha o `allDay: true`.
Aí ele aparece a cor de fundo sem a bolinha, o que eu preciso é que apareça a cor de fundo com a bolinha, para a bolinha ser indicador de status, e a cor de fundo indicador de tarefas. Com isso, eu parti da premissa de alterar o codigo fonte da biblioteca e encontrei o seguinte codigo:

```
TableListItemEvent.prototype.render = function () {
            var _a = this, props = _a.props, context = _a.context;
            var timeFormat = context.options.eventTimeFormat || DEFAULT_TABLE_EVENT_TIME_FORMAT;
            var timeText = buildSegTimeText(props.seg, timeFormat, context, true, props.defaultDisplayEventEnd);
  
            return (createElement(EventRoot, { seg: props.seg, timeText: timeText, defaultContent: renderInnerContent$2, isDragging: props.isDragging, isResizing: false, isDateSelecting: false, isSelected: props.isSelected, isPast: props.isPast, isFuture: props.isFuture, isToday: props.isToday }, function (rootElRef, classNames, innerElRef, innerContent) { return ( // we don't use styles!
            createElement("a", __assign({ className: ['fc-daygrid-event', 'fc-daygrid-dot-event',eventDef.publicId].concat(classNames).join(' '), ref: rootElRef }, getSegAnchorAttrs$1(props.seg)), innerContent)); }));
        };
```

se incluir o:

```
style:{backgroundColor:'#345674',color:'#FFF'}
```

desta forma:

```
TableListItemEvent.prototype.render = function () {
            var _a = this, props = _a.props, context = _a.context;
            var timeFormat = context.options.eventTimeFormat || DEFAULT_TABLE_EVENT_TIME_FORMAT;
            var timeText = buildSegTimeText(props.seg, timeFormat, context, true, props.defaultDisplayEventEnd);
            return (createElement(EventRoot, { seg: props.seg, timeText: timeText, defaultContent: renderInnerContent$2, isDragging: props.isDragging, isResizing: false, isDateSelecting: false, isSelected: props.isSelected, isPast: props.isPast, isFuture: props.isFuture, isToday: props.isToday }, function (rootElRef, classNames, innerElRef, innerContent) { return ( // we don't use styles!
            createElement("a", __assign({ className: ['fc-daygrid-event', 'fc-daygrid-dot-event',eventDef.publicId].concat(classNames).join(' '),style:{backgroundColor:'#345674',color:'#FFF'}, ref: rootElRef }, getSegAnchorAttrs$1(props.seg)), innerContent)); }));
        };
```

atende ao que preciso. Porém não quero passar apenas uma cor estatica, quero poder escolher a cor na hora de incluir o evento.
Não precisa ser necessariamente alterando a biblioteca, se alguém tiver outra forma de fazer isto.?